# Flask-SQLAlchemy not saving database updates

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to import data into existing database items. There are two fields that I want to update for each data base item: a string type field caled `imagefolder` and a picketype (list) field called `images`. The input values for both fields are strings that store file paths.

My steps are to query the database item, check for its existance, and then update its fields.

```
blend = Blend.query.filter_by(old_ID=row[4]).first()
if blend:
    blend.imagefolder = "/".join((row[16].split("/")[4:])[:-1])
    blend.images.append(ntpath.basename(row[16]))
    db.session.commit()
```

When I run the script nothing happens (the database doesn't update), and I noticed that the import script runs really quickly, too quickly.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `old_ID==row[4]`?  (Two equal signs...)

Comment: filter() uses expressions, filter_by() uses parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to add changed object to current session.

And try the following snippet.

```
blend = db.session.query(Blend).filter_by(old_ID=row[4]).first()
if blend:
    blend.imagefolder = "/".join((row[16].split("/")[4:])[:-1])
    blend.images.append(ntpath.basename(row[16]))
    db.session.add(blend)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: I tried that and it gave an error saying it was already in the session.